TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime
I have the following class code:
import datetime

class Persona:

    def __init__(self, nom, dni, fecha_nac):
        self.nom=nom
        self.dni=dni
        self.fecha_nac=fecha_nac

    def es_mayor_edad(self):
       today=datetime.date.today()
       cumple = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.fecha_nac, "%Y-%m-%d")
       edad = today.year - cumple.year

       if (today.month < cumple.month) or (today.month == cumple.month and today.day < cumple.day):
            edad = edad - 1

       if edad>=18:
           return True

       else:
           return False

    def __str__(self):
        string = f"Nombre: {self.nom}\tDNI: {self.dni}\tFecha de nacimiento: {str(self.fecha_nac)}"
        return string

And then, the following code in the main program:
from Ejercicio_4 import Persona
import datetime

nom=input("Introduce el nombre de la persona: ")
dni=input("Introduce el DNI de dicha persona: ")
fecha_nac_str=input("Introduce fecha nacimiento:[dd/mm/aaaa]: ")
fecha_nac= datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha_nac_str, "%d/%m/%Y")

persona=Persona(nom,dni,fecha_nac)
persona.es_mayor_edad()

print(persona)

if persona.es_mayor_edad()==True:
    print(f"{persona.nom} es mayor de edad")

else:
    print(f"{persona.nom} NO es mayor de edad")

I am trying to obtain a date from fecha_nac_str (which is in string form) to feed to my persona class variable, but when running the code I obtain the following error:
File "C:\...\Ejercicio_4_main.py", line 10, in <module>
    persona.es_mayor_edad()
  File "C:...\Ejercicio_4.py", line 12, in es_mayor_edad
    cumple = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.fecha_nac, "%Y-%m-%d")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime

How could I fix this?

You have already converted the str to datetime in this statement: fecha_nac= datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha_nac_str, "%d/%m/%Y") before creating persona! Perhaps you wanted persona=Persona(nom,dni,fecha_nac_str) Oh and I'm not sure today.year - cumple.year will yield what you want; perhaps getting the number of years from today - cumple would be better.

The problem is that in your code, you're trying to parse a datetime object again when it's already been parsed. Here's how to fix it:
# In your Persona class
import datetime

class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nom, dni, fecha_nac):
        self.nom = nom
        self.dni = dni
        self.fecha_nac = fecha_nac  # This is already a datetime object
        
    def es_mayor_edad(self):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        # No need to parse fecha_nac again since it's already a datetime object
        cumple = self.fecha_nac.date()  # Convert to date object for comparison
        edad = today.year - cumple.year
        if (today.month < cumple.month) or (today.month == cumple.month and today.day < cumple.day):
            edad = edad - 1
        return edad >= 18
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Nombre: {self.nom}\tDNI: {self.dni}\tFecha de nacimiento: {self.fecha_nac.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"

then,
# In your main program
from Ejercicio_4 import Persona
import datetime

nom = input("Introduce el nombre de la persona: ")
dni = input("Introduce el DNI de dicha persona: ")
fecha_nac_str = input("Introduce fecha nacimiento:[dd/mm/aaaa]: ")
fecha_nac = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha_nac_str, "%d/%m/%Y")
persona = Persona(nom, dni, fecha_nac)

if persona.es_mayor_edad():
    print(f"{persona.nom} es mayor de edad")
else:
    print(f"{persona.nom} NO es mayor de edad")
print(persona)

Output:
Introduce el nombre de la persona: ada
dIntroduce el DNI de dicha persona: dd
Introduce fecha nacimiento:[dd/mm/aaaa]: 18/12/1990
ad es mayor de edad
Nombre: ad  DNI: dd Fecha de nacimiento: 1990-12-18

